# Identify tab that made request in Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using the [Firefox Addon SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/dev-guide/welcome.html) to build something that monitors and displays the HTTP traffic in the browser. Similar to [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) or [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/). I am interested in identifying which tab in the browser (if any) generated the request

Using the [observer-service](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/packages/api-utils/docs/observer-service.html) I am monitoring for "http-on-examine-response" events. I have code like the following to identify the nsIDomWindow that generated the request:

```
const observer = require("observer-service"),
    {Ci} = require("chrome");

function getTabFromChannel(channel) {
    try {
        var noteCB= channel.notificationCallbacks ? channel.notificationCallbacks : channel.loadGroup.notificationCallbacks;

        if (!noteCB) { return null; }

        var domWin = noteCB.getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
        return domWin.top;
    } catch (e) {
        dump(e + "\n");
        return null;
    }
}

function logHTTPTraffic(sub, data) {
    sub.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
    var ab = getTabFromChannel(sub);
    console.log(tab);
}

observer.add("http-on-examine-response", logHTTPTraffic);
```

Mostly cribbed from the [documentation for how to identify the browser that generated the request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Getting_the_browser_that_fires_the_http-on-modify-request_notification). Some is also taken from the [Google PageSpeed](https://code.google.com/p/page-speed/source/browse/firefox_addon/trunk/src/pagespeed_firefox/js/components/componentCollectorService.js?r=1304) Firefox addon.

Is there a recommended or preferred way to go from the [nsIDOMWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMWindow) object `domWin` to a tab element in the [SDK tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/packages/addon-kit/docs/tabs.html) module?

I've considered something hacky like scanning the tabs list for one with a URL that matches the URL for domWin, but then I have to worry about multiple tabs having the same URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keep using the internal packages. From what I can tell, `getTabForWindow()` function in `api-utils/lib/tabs/tab.js` package does exactly what you want. Untested code:

```
var tabsLib = require("sdk/tabs/tab.js");
return tabsLib.getTabForWindow(domWin.top);
```

Comment: Awesome that works great! Guess I need to keep an eye on the source and the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The API has changed since this was originally asked/answered...
It should now (as of 1.15) be:

```
return require("sdk/tabs/utils").getTabForWindow(domWin.top);
```

Comment: Now it calls getTabForContentWindow

Answer (score 0):

As of Addon SDK version 1.13 change:

`var tabsLib = require("tabs/tab.js");`

to

`var tabsLib = require("sdk/tabs/helpers.js");`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still cares about this:

Although the Addon SDK is being deprecated in support of the newer WebExtensions API, I want to point out that

var a_tab = require("sdk/tabs/utils").getTabForContentWindow(window)

returns a different 'tab' object than the one you would typically get by using

worker.tab in a PageMod.

For example, a_tab will not have the 'id' attribute, but would have linkedPanel property that's similar to the 'id' attribute.