# How to get tab from loading resource at nsIContentPolicy shouldLoad

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an extension on Firefox's Addon SDK (v1.9). My extension blocks or allows resources by implementing nsIContentPolicy and testing their URIs against a database of URIs to block.

**Problem**

I need to have access to the tab object (if available) from the shouldLoad function of nsIContentPolicy.

I assume the part to use for this is the "context" parameter on the shouldLoad function which is nsISupports. I have tried using getTabForWindow(win) with no luck since context is not nsIDOMWindow ([Identify tab that made request in Firefox Addon SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098580/identify-tab-that-made-request-in-firefox-addon-sdk))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `context` parameter is either a document or an element. Getting from there to a window isn't hard:

```js
var {Ci} = require("chrome");
if (!(context instanceof Ci.nsIDOMWindow))
{
  // If this is an element, get the corresponding document
  if (context instanceof Ci.nsIDOMNode && context.ownerDocument)
    context = context.ownerDocument;

  // Now we should have a document, get its window
  if (context instanceof Ci.nsIDOMDocument)
    context = context.defaultView;
  else
    context = null;
}

// If we have a window now - get the tab
if (context)
{
  var tabsLib = require("tabs/tab.js");
  return tabsLib.getTabForWindow(context.top);
}
else
  return null;
```

For reference: [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node), [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document),[window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window).

Comment: Thanks again for the help. The reason why it would not work for me when trying to figure this out is because I was trying to get the tab from the context of a main_frame (TYPE_DOCUMENT) resource loading. And this still is not able to do so, is it possible at all to get the tab from a main_frame resource?

Comment: So I figured out main_frames (TYPE_DOCUMENT) have a XULElement as context, so we already have the window object by calling context._contentWindow.top, which when used with getTabForWindow(), gives the correct tab object. So to post the complete answer, the question should be how to test context for XULElement.

Comment: or we could just test for context._contentWindow !== undefined

Comment: @josesigna: Sounds like you are looking at [`<xul:browser>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/browser) that the document is loaded into.

Comment: @WladimirPalant I just noticed that `shouldLoad` is called twice for requests from an `nsIDOMNode`. The first time the `ownerDocument` property of the node is null. The second time it is set. Have you not experienced this? I guess this might be behavior that has changed in Firefox in the last year.

Comment: @MatthewGertner: Sure, see [bug 612921](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=612921). That change is pretty old however, it was introduced in Firefox 3.6.

Comment: @WladimirPalant I'm always the last to know. :-) Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @MatthewGertner: The answer already considers that - the context will be the document for speculative loads. As long as we are only interested in the tab this doesn't really matter.

Comment: @WladimirPalant What I experienced is that the node is the context both times but the `ownerDocument` member is null the first time. But it's true that there's not much you can do for the first call except ignore it. I just thought it might be worth mentioning this behavior since it's somewhat surprising for someone who implements the code in your answer.

Comment: @MatthewGertner: A document is also a node - and its `ownerDocument` propery is always `null`. So the first check (`context instanceof Ci.nsIDOMNode && context.ownerDocument`) will fail while the second (`context instanceof Ci.nsIDOMDocument`) succeeds.