# Get window object from tab

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an extension on Firefox's Addon SDK (v1.10).

My extension has a toolbarbutton that updates a small badge to its left based on the contents of the active tab.

**Problem**

When there is more than one window open, the toolbarbutton gets updated to the value of the active tab, regardless of whether or not it is on the same window. This means that the non active window's toolbarbutton is getting updated with data coming from a different window.

Having access to the tab object from where the data comes from, is there a way to identify the window object the tab is attached to?

It would be the opposite of this method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8103203/1560260).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the SDK source code (namely `packages/api-utils/lib/tabs/tab.js`), a `tab` object actually has a `window` property. I tested it and this works indeed:

```js
console.log(require("tabs").activeTab.window.title);
```

Not sure why this property isn't documented, probably a documentation bug.

Answer (score 1):

Would this be the active window? You can get a window object for the current active window using

```
windows.browserWindows.activeWindow
```

Docs: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/windows.html#browserWindows

The window object has a list of tabs currently open in it:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/windows.html#tabs

If you need to find a tab in a window that isn't the current active tab or window, that might be more difficult to determine. Can you provide more detail about what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: My extension performs calculations on each open tab and displays the results by showing a small badge with a number on a toolbarbutton I created. These calculations are dynamic, and happen at any point in time (not only when the tab is active or loading). As of now, I perform the calculations and update the badge on the toolbarbutton when a tab is made active, so as to always display the correspondent badge to the tab being used. The problem comes when 2 or more windows are open at the same time. How can I identify in which window I should be updating the button's badge?

Comment: And using activeWindow is out of the question because of the dynamic nature of my extension's calculations: I could be using a different window while my extension is recording info on another open window.